# Looping inside onPostExecute AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to store my image into external storage and the directory location in SQLite database. I just confused sometime it works well. But sometimes the looping is not doing correctly.

This is my code :

```
class GetLength extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String nama_kategori,img_kategori,kode_kategori;
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        ArrayList<String> img_ktgrs = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> kode_ktgrs = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i=0;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this,"In Progress","Loading...",true);
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a", "a"));
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://xxx.php", "POST", param);
                JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("categories");
                jArray = array.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    kode_kategori = row.getString("kode_kategori_produk");
                    nama_kategori = row.getString("nama_kategori_produk");
                    img_kategori = row.getString("img_kategori_produk");
                    img_ktgrs.add(img_kategori);
                    kode_ktgrs.add(kode_kategori);
                    myDb2.insertKategori(kode_kategori,nama_kategori,kode_kategori + ".jpg");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            img_ktgr = new String[img_ktgrs.size()];
            img_ktgr = img_ktgrs.toArray(img_ktgr);
            kode_ktgr = new String[kode_ktgrs.size()];
            kode_ktgr = kode_ktgrs.toArray(kode_ktgr);
            int j = img_ktgrs.size();

            for (i=0;i<j;i++) {
                x = i;

                Picasso.with(Home.this)
                        .load(img_ktgr[x])
                        .into(new Target() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                      try {
                                          String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                          File myDir = new File(root + "/BlanjaPasar/Kategori");

                                          if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                              myDir.mkdirs();
                                          }

                                          String name = kode_ktgr[x] + ".jpg";
                                          myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                                          FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                                          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                                          out.flush();
                                          out.close();
                                          System.out.println("Here Url :" + name);

                                      } catch (Exception e) {
                                          // some action
                                      }
                                  }

                                  @Override
                                  public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                  }

                                  @Override
                                  public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                                  }
                              }
                );System.out.println("X : " + x);
            }
            CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),KategoriProduk.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

Im doing that looping inside onPostExecute. Take a look in this :

```
String name = kode_ktgr[x] + ".jpg";
myDir = new File(myDir, name);
```

Sometimes that x value is stuck on 1. But when i check using System.out.println , the value is changing.

Comment: you mean sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Try to use Threads instead of AsyncTask

Comment: please make your problem more clear to get better help!

Comment: Sometime the value is kode_ktgr-001 , kode_ktgr-001, kode_ktgr-001, kode_ktgr-001. But sometimes it works like : kode_ktgr-001 , kode_ktgr-002, kode_ktgr-003, kode_ktgr-004

Comment: onPostExecute runs on the main/UI thread, looping on the main thread is highly discouraged because most often it leads to ANR.